# In PHP, should I delete objects immediately after use?

Tags: php, object-oriented, programming-practices, class

I've read in *PHP Advanced and Object Oriented Programming* by Larry Ullman that it is good programming practice to delete object immediately after use but reason is given nowhere.

I am a student web developer and objects in web applications are deleted automatically as soon as the script finishes. So, there seems no good reason to delete them manually.

So, my question is what are the good reasons to delete unnecessary objects after use other that blindly following a convention?

Comment: where did you read this?

Comment: Depends heavily on language. Most languages with GC don't even have option to delete an object.

Comment: @gnat in books.

Comment: in which books? name at least one

Comment: @gnat PHP Advanced and Object Oriented Programming by Larry Ullman

Comment: Can anyone explain reasons for downvoted. Isn't this on topic here?

Comment: @gnat >>You don’t technically have to delete the
object—it will be deleted as soon as the
script ends. Still, I think it’s **better** programming
form to tidy up like this.

Comment: until you clarified about the book and language, the question did not make sense - I think that's why it was downvoted

Comment: This is actually a very good question. PHP is a mess of a framework in many ways, however it's memory management issues are being fixed and poor resource management (within scripts) will soon become inexcusable. Yes, unset resources unless you know that its unnecessary for a specific resource/object.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to delete an object after its use in PHP.  Let PHP's garbage collection take care of it for you.

There *may* be some obscure performance reasons to unset an object after you are done with it in very specific situations.  But such cases are not everyday events, and they will be clear when you see them.

Comment: Database connections / result sets? Very Large strings that you won't touch again?

Comment: They still get freed when they go out of scope and/or the script ends.  There's no necessity to manually delete them unless there's some specific problem you're encountering, like building memory usage.  I've had to do that a couple times when reading very large xml files, for example.

Comment: I mention the database because I've seen code that has left the database result set in scope for much longer than needed... which meant that the cursor was open on the database which was then hitting resource constraints on *another* machine (this was back in the perl.cgi days - different, but similar).

Comment: @GrandmasterB Can you give me an example of `obscure performance reasons`.

Comment: @MichaelT I saw that sort of thing as well back in my powerbuilder days.  The PHP data classes I've worked with all pull the full results back in one shot and close the cursor, so that you dont have one hanging around while the php script executes.

Comment: @SantaClaus The one case in particular I mentioned was processing a very large xml file.  I remember having to specifically unset the objects because memory usage was causing the script to run afoul of the limits.  I did the same another time when generating a very large text data file.  I've only had to do it a couple times, and I've been coding in PHP since PHP3.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's GC was hit and miss prior to 5.3 with many arrays and objects becoming unfreeable until the script ended. Because of this, PHP development basically took on an unspoken “who needs GC anyways” attitude because vars were only guaranteed to be freed when the script ended.

Two things are happening which change this:

First, PHP's GC has advanced to where its only unreliable with  arrays that contain copies of other arrays. PHP's GC will be totally functional and reliable once this issue is fixed .

Secondly, PHP's pthread extension is coming along pretty well. It's very likely that PHP will have full thread support within the next couple years, making long running scripts as usefull as many Java appliations.

These two things are likely to change many standards in the way PHP is used. For example, your already starting to see serious efforts to create PHP based network services (such as [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)) now that the GC is reliable under most circumstances.

So to make a long story short -  no, your currently not required to unset any form of resources in PHP because they will all be freed when the script ends. However, unsetting objects and other resources *will* make sure that each unneeded resource is freed *before* the script ends, potentially freeing up highly contented resources and thus improve performance.

Moreover, the practice of unsetting objects and resources is likely to become the norm in the near future, and likely an absolute requirement in many cases.

Note that many PHP objects/resources don't fall out of scope until the script ends. This means that unset() is the only way to ensure that their ref count is set to 0 in order to become a candidate for freeing by the GC (before the script ends, that is.)

Comment: Where is possible to read more on the actual state of the Garbage Collector? I'm mainly interested in knowing if unsetting a tree-object (with a deep nesting of other objects) does make sense, if it will be freed when needed automatically or if it will happen just when the script will end (because I'd like to free memory when the method, or the class is used&ended).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Comment: Also see http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php